# How do I deploy my existing SPSS streams takes input from DB using WML in Watson Studio

Tags: machine-learning, setup-deployment, spss-modeler, watson-studio

Earlier when Machine Learning service was part of Bluemix, I use to deploy my SPSS Modeler streams easily and these SPSS streams where having Dashdb connectivity through Json Script. However, in Watson Studio, I do not find that connectivity for WML. Can you please guide

1. If I can deploy my existing SPSS Modeler (version 18) Streams which are having DB connectivity for input and output in Watson Studio?
2. I yes, can you point to the documentation or tutorial and also, can I import .str files into WML as it use to be case earlier?
3. If not, what is the best way to do that? Why this useful feature is taken away? Any plans to include that again?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can import SPSS Modeler version 18 Stream by simply
Open Watson Studio Project -> Add to Project -> Modeler Flow
[image]

Use "From File" option -> browse or drag and drop your stream file.
[image]

Now regarding database connectivity, you can add a connection to your database
from watson studio project and then you can create or reuse your input node from strea
and then simply choose location as connection(from connection select table) that you created.

Now may be all type of database connections may not be supported but i tested Db2 warehouse on cloud and i was able to use it for input node in this stream.